# Оптимизация вставки или обновления множества значений в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Каждый раз после определенных манипуляций получается некий массив с уникальными словами:

```
$words = array(
  "cat",
  "dog",
  "mouse",
  "home",
  ...
);
```

1. Нужно каждое слово сохранить в таблице, если оно там не встречается и задать ему счетчик = 1.
2. Если слово встречается, то увеличить счетчик данного слова на 1.

С этим в принципе проблем нет, вопрос в другом. Иногда приходит массив на 1000 слов, и в целом может прийти и неограниченно больше. Сейчас проверка и запись в базу происходит тупо в цикле по одному.

Вопрос такой: можно ли как-то это оптимизировать, например, как-то обновлять таблицу одним запросом. Если да, то не будет ли какое ограничение по длине запроса. В целом, как бы вы сделали, посоветуйте варианты.

Comment: insert into words (word, counter) values (?, 1),(?, 1),(?, 1),(?, 1)  on duplicate key update counter=counter+1

Comment: При этом каким местом здесь *подсчет слов в базе данных* - абсолютно не ясно

Comment: *разумеется*, для запроса выше на слове должен стоять уникальный индекс

Comment: Создание уникального индекса с [английского СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149891/9816116)

Comment: Как быть с ограничением на длину запроса в разных бд.